# RestSharp doesn't serialize DateTime on Get request?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm making a `GET` request with RestSharp from one API to another, but when I pass a `DateTime` in the url, it gives me an error saying that I send a bad resquet and that some parameter that isn't nullable, is null.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ValidadeX(long operationId, long equipmentId, string date, long? lines)
{
    // string date = "17/09/2019 00:00:00"
    var dateParameter = DateTime.Parse(date).ToString(); // It works and creates a DateTime object with no problem

    var apiEndPoint = $"XController/ValidadeX?operationId={operationId}&equipmentId={equipmentId}&date={dateParameter}&lines={(lines?.ToString() ?? "null")}";

    var result = RestHelper.Get<bool>(apiEndPoint);

    return ...

}
```

`RestHelper` is just a helper that adds Authorization and Headers, but all it do is create a `new RestRequest(apiEndPoint, method)` and execute the resquest.

In the other controller, I have

```
public HttpResponseMessage ValidadeModVerPerformance(long operationId, long equipmentId, DateTime date, long? lines)
{
    return ...
}
```

And the error I'm getting it is

> "{\"Message\":\"The request is invalid.\",\"MessageDetail\":\"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'date' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage ValidadeModVerPerformance(Int64, Int64, System.DateTime, System.Nullable`1[System.Int64])' in 'XController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.\"}"

Comment: Does `DateTime.Parse(date)` work? What value does `dateParameter` have? (i'm guessing it is `null`) What value does `date` have?

Comment: @phuzi, yes, it works and comes with the correct date, it isn't null. I also updated that on the question

Comment: Have you tried using the format string for the date in your interpolated string?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: You're using string interpolation to concatenate the `DateTime` into the URL `apiEndPoint`. It may be that default converter for `DateTime` doesn't like the default output of `DateTime.ToString()`. You probably want to use something like `dateParameter.ToString("u")`...

Comment: What format should it be so it works?

Comment: @Vencovsky I guess time is causing an issue in RestSharp
Please replace with `var dateParameter = DateTime.Parse(date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`